# LeetCode 200: Number of Islands

Tags: c++, beginner, programming-challenge, comparative-review, c++17

I'm posting my code for a LeetCode problem. If you'd like to review, please do so. Thank you for your time!

### Problem

> Given a 2d grid map of '1's (land) and '0's (water), count the number
> of islands. An island is surrounded by water and is formed by
> connecting adjacent lands horizontally or vertically. You may assume
> all four edges of the grid are all surrounded by water.
>
> #### Example 1:
>
> ```
> Input:
> 11110
> 11010
> 11000
> 00000
>
> Output: 1
> ```
>
> #### Example 2:
>
> ```
> Input:
> 11000
> 11000
> 00100
> 00011
>
> Output: 3
> ```

#### Code

```
#include <vector>

class Solution {
public:
    std::size_t numIslands(std::vector<std::vector<char>>& grid) {
        std::size_t row_length = grid.size();

        if (!row_length) {
            return 0;
        }

        std::size_t col_length = grid[0].size();
        std::size_t islands = 0;

        // Runs depth first search for every cell
        for (std::size_t row = 0; row < row_length; row++) {
            for (std::size_t col = 0; col < col_length; col++) {
                if (grid[row][col] == '1') {
                    islands++;
                    depth_first_search(grid, row, col, row_length, col_length);
                }
            }
        }

        return islands;
    }

private:
    void depth_first_search(std::vector<std::vector<char>>& grid, const std::size_t row, const std::size_t col, const std::size_t row_length, const std::size_t col_length) {
        // Checks for grid boundaries and '0' cells
        if (row < 0 || row >= row_length || col < 0 || col >= col_length || grid[row][col] == '0') {
            return;
        }

        grid[row][col] = '0';
        // Recurse in 4 directions of grid
        depth_first_search(grid, row + 1, col, row_length, col_length);
        depth_first_search(grid, row - 1, col, row_length, col_length);
        depth_first_search(grid, row, col + 1, row_length, col_length);
        depth_first_search(grid, row, col - 1, row_length, col_length);
    }
};
```

#### LeetCode's Solution (Not for review)

```
class Solution {
private:
  void dfs(vector<vector<char>>& grid, int r, int c) {
    int nr = grid.size();
    int nc = grid[0].size();

    grid[r][c] = '0';
    if (r - 1 >= 0 && grid[r-1][c] == '1') dfs(grid, r - 1, c);
    if (r + 1 < nr && grid[r+1][c] == '1') dfs(grid, r + 1, c);
    if (c - 1 >= 0 && grid[r][c-1] == '1') dfs(grid, r, c - 1);
    if (c + 1 < nc && grid[r][c+1] == '1') dfs(grid, r, c + 1);
  }

public:
  int numIslands(vector<vector<char>>& grid) {
    int nr = grid.size();
    if (!nr) return 0;
    int nc = grid[0].size();

    int num_islands = 0;
    for (int r = 0; r < nr; ++r) {
      for (int c = 0; c < nc; ++c) {
        if (grid[r][c] == '1') {
          ++num_islands;
          dfs(grid, r, c);
        }
      }
    }

    return num_islands;
  }
};
```

#### Reference

On LeetCode, there is a class usually named `Solution` with one or more `public` functions which we are not allowed to rename.

- [Problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-islands/)
- [Discuss](https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-islands/discuss/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Offload more functionality into `depth_first_search()`

One improvement your solution has over LeetCode's is that you move the grid boundary check into `depth_first_search()`. However, you can do more, by having it return whether you are starting on an island or in the ocean:

```
bool depth_first_search(...) {
    // Checks for grid boundaries and '0' cells
    if (...)
        return false;

    // We are on an island, recurse
    ...

    return true;
}
```

Then, the loop inside `numIslands()` can be simplified:

```
for (std::size_t row = 0; row < row_length; row++)
    for (std::size_t col = 0; col < col_length; col++)
        islands += depth_first_search(grid, row, col, row_length, col_length);
```

## Naming things

While `depth_first_search()` does iterate in a depth-first fashion, it is not search for anything. Rather, it is implementing a [flood fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) algorithm. But here we use it to remove an island. If it also performs a check to see if there is an island at the given position, I would name it `check_and_remove_island()`. As Emily L. mentions, a function name that reads like `foo_and_bar()` is usually a hint that it should be split into a `foo()` and `bar()`. If you want to go that way, I suggest you make it so you can write the following code:

```
if (is_island(grid, row, col)) {
    islands++;
    remove_island(grid, row, col);
}
```

## Get rid of the size variables

I don't think it's that useful to store the sizes into separate variables, and to pass them explicitly to `depth_first_search()`. This information can always easily be gotten from the variable `grid`. This also gets rid of the check for an empty grid:

```
std::size_t numIslands(std::vector<std::vector<char>>& grid) {
    size_t islands{};

    for(std::size_t row = 0; row < grid.size(); row++)
        for (std::size_t col = 0; col < grid[row].size(); col++)
            islands += check_and_remove_island(grid, row, col);

    return islands;
}
```

You have to modify `depth_first_search()` to match of course.

Comment: I disagree with moving the island check into the DFS routine. Although clever and more compact, it conflates responsibilities. The method should then be called check_island_and_remove() and that's a smell to me.

Comment: In fact the name DFS is also wrong, it's not a search as much as a flood fill implemented with depth first recursion. But I digress...

Comment: @EmilyL. Separating responsibilities is usually a good thing, but I think that here conflating them does make the code nicer overall. But I totally agree about `depth_first_search()` needing a different name!

Comment: Perhaps `flood`